# Webpack 4 unable to built production for web

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am breaking my head, trying to understand why this production build is not working on the browser.

So basically I have a development config that works flawlessly, but the production build keeps displaying for some weird reason `Error: Minified React error #200; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.` on the console.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Here is my folder structure

[image]

`package.json`

```
"build": "webpack --config=config/webpack.config.js --env production --progress",
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config=config/webpack.config.js --env development --open"
```

And `webpack.config.js` (I have omitted the developer config since it works fine )

```
... 
// Paths
getPaths = ({
  sourceDir = '../app', 
  distDir = '../dist', 
  staticDir = 'static', 
  images = 'images', 
  fonts = 'fonts', 
  scripts = 'scripts', 
  styles = 'styles'} = {}) => {
    const assets = { images, fonts, scripts, styles }
    return Object.keys(assets).reduce((obj, assetName) => {
      const assetPath = assets[assetName]
      obj[assetName] = !staticDir ? assetPath : `${staticDir}/${assetPath}`
      return obj
    },{
      app: path.join(__dirname, sourceDir),
      dist: path.join(__dirname, distDir),
      staticDir
    })
},
paths = getPaths(),
publicPath = '',


// Main module
commonConfig = merge([{
  context: paths.app,
  resolve: {
    unsafeCache: true,
    symlinks: false
  },
  entry: [`${paths.app}/scripts/index.jsx`, `${paths.app}/styles/styles.scss`],
  output: { path: paths.dist, publicPath },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlPlugin(),
  ]
  },
  load.Html(),
 })
]),

// Build
productionConfig = merge([
  {
    mode: 'production'
  },
  load.Scripts({
    include: paths.app,
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    options: { 
      configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'babel.config.js'),
    }
  }),

  load.ExtractCSS({
    include: paths.app,
    options: {
      filename: `${paths.styles}/[name].min.[contenthash:8].css`,
      chunkFilename: `${paths.styles}/[id].[contenthash:8].css`,
      publicPath: '../'   
    }
  })
]),

// Merge module
module.exports = env => {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = env
  return merge(commonConfig, env === 'production' ? productionConfig : developmentConfig
  )
}
```

And finally the referenced modules `webpack.modules.js`

```
exports.Html = () => ({
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})



exports.MinifyCSS = ({ options }) => ({
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
        cssProcessorOptions: options,
        canPrint: true // false for analyzer
      })
    ]
  }
})


exports.ExtractCSS = ({ include, exclude, options } = {}) => ({
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      include,
      exclude,
      use: [
        { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, options: { publicPath: '../../'  } },
        'css-loader', 
        { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')] }}, 
        'fast-sass-loader'
        ]
    }]
  },
  plugins: [ new MiniCssExtractPlugin(options) ]
})


exports.Scripts = ({ include, exclude, options } = {}) => ({
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      include, 
      exclude,
      use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader', options }]
    }]
  }
})
```

After runing `npm run build` when I open the website on `https://localhost/React/Transcript/dist/` I get:

`Error: Minified React error #200; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.`

Comment: I would start by trying to pinpoint the differences between your development and production config. Maybe try removing entries from your production config one by one until you no longer get that error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have been working on this for the past 5 hours non stop, but no matter how much a strip it, it does not work. The dev config is very different as it does not create any files, it works on memory with the src files. Is not so much an error as how it seems to prepare the files for server side node execution and not the browser.

Comment: Try adding `"target": "web"`? That should be the default but it may have gotten messed up.

Comment: @john Wilson I tried that, no changes.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `"externals"` field in your production config?

Comment: @john Wilson I tried that too, sorry I should have removed the line as I was trying something

Comment: what is the rest of the stack trace displayed in your browser console?

Comment: @Dan O  Amending post to display that

Comment: Could you try removing the `noParse` section, some dependencies might load the minified version if they detect a production build. Also if you enable source maps in production, they should point out what dependency is making the bad require call.

Comment: @Ferrybig That did something, now I get `Error: Minified React error #200; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. ` I have seen this before but the link takes you no where really, It seems to be saying `Target container is not a DOM element.`

Comment: @Ferrybig Thanks mate you send me on the right direction, I needed to remove that + adding `{ template: './index.html'}` to the `HtmlPlugin`. It's now Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone on the comment section for helping me find the problem, it turns out that I had to remove the `module: { noParse: /\.min\.js/ }` from the common config and add `new HtmlPlugin({ template: './index.html'})` instead of just `new HtmlPlugin()`